# unrecognized configuration parameter "custom_variable_classes"

Tags: postgresql

I get this message after a system update:

```
unrecognized configuration parameter "custom_variable_classes" in file "/var/lib/pgsql/data/postgresql.conf" line 501
```

Are custom variable classes not supported any more?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Since version 9.2 this statement is not needed any more:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/release-9-2.html#AEN111020

Just remove or uncomment the line:

```
#custom_variable_classes = 'foo'             # list of custom variable class names
foo.bar=0
```